# How to Remove Line from LineChart?

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to figure out how to remove a plotted line from a LineChart once it has already been made. I have tried just recreating the scene with the series I do want, but that didn't work. I have done some troubleshooting and found that the series is in fact changed and reduced to null, but the line persists even though the series is empty. Then once you change the series to new numbers it tries to connect the points to the old points that aren't supposed to exist. If someone could help me with this it would be very much appreciated.

```
public class GraphSection {
NumberAxis xAxis;
NumberAxis yAxis;
LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;
Scene scene;
XYChart.Series series1, series2, series3, series4;




public GraphSection(){
    xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Test Graph");
    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

    series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series4 = new XYChart.Series();

    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3, series4);
    scene = new Scene(lineChart,400,300);


}
public Scene getGraph(){
    return this.scene;

}
public void addPoints(int n){

    if(n == 1){
        //Test Points
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1,50));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2,60));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3,70));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4,80));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5,90));

    }
    else if(n == 2){
        //More Test Points
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1,70));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2,80));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3,90));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4,100));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5,110));
    }
    else if(n == 3){

    }
    else if(n == 4){

    }

}

public void removePoints(int n){
    Series s;
    LineChart l = this.lineChart;
    if(n == 1){
        s = this.series1;
        s.getData().clear();
        l.removeSeriesFromDisplay(s);  //This is the method I would guess I need but 
                                       //it is "not visible" and thus produces
                                       // an error when I try to compile.
    }
    else if(n==2){
        series2 = this.series2;
    }
    else if(n==3){
        series3 = this.series3;
    }
    else if(n==4){
        series4 = this.series4;
    }


}

}
```

EDIT: So while `.remove()` will work to get it to remove the line from the graph it also throws the IllegalStateException. This, while ugly, doesn't cause the program to crash, however, then when I add data points back into the series it will not graph the new points. So a potential solution would be to dynamically add a series into the LineChart. If anyone knows how to do this, that might solve my problem.

EDIT: I have changed .addPoints(2); to add points to the series1 and I am including pictures below (Adding after the remove() just gives a blank chart).I am also including the code I am calling the class from.

```
    //Bottom
    JFXPanel bottom = new JFXPanel();
    final GraphSection gs = new GraphSection();
    bottom.setScene(gs.getGraph());
    gs.addPoints(1);

    //ActionListeners
    testButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            gs.removePoints(1);
            System.out.println(gs.series1.getData()); //Used for debugging
        }
    });

    testButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            gs.addPoints(2);
            System.out.println(gs.series1.getData());
        }
    });
```

[Start with .addPoints(1);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GKMi.jpg)
[This is what happens with just .getData().clear();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecV6E.jpg)

Comment: `lineChart.getData().remove(series1)`?

Comment: gave that a shot and produced an IllegalStateException

Comment: WELL. Actually it gives this error, but then it actually does remove the line... huh. Any way to make it so it DOESNT throw the error?

Comment: Where are you calling the `removePoints(...)` method from?

Comment: A button with an actionlistener on it.

Comment: Post the tracktrace of the exception, it may be caused by your own code.

Comment: Also post the code of how you re-adding the new data to the "removed" series.

Comment: I think the problem might actually be from trying to integrate a JFXPanel into a Swing GUI then still expecting dynamic changes. I have had some success from running the same class inside a javafx stage. Under these circumstances it no longer throws the IllegalStateException and I can dynamically add new series. Therefore Im going to try to use SwingNodes instead of JFXPanels to use JavaFX as the base. I will update to let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was in fact trying to use a JFXPanel within a Swing JFrame. This meant that illegalStateException was popping up as a result. By altering the code to run on a JavaFX stage this allowed for remove() to work, and then you can easily dynamically add new series with lineChart.getData().add(Series);. You can incorporate swing components with SwingNodes, though my advice would be to recode your GUI into all JavaFX.